# freetextbox spellchecking not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, spell-checking, freetextbox

I have an .aspx page and am using the FTB:FreeTextBox control. Seems to be working fine except in conjunction with the jQuery spellchecker. In IE the spell checking is not working in the textbox.

Is there something specific that its looking for to get it to work in IE?